# Почему может не работать команда | await ctx.channel.purge(limit=2) | и как её решить? | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Проблема в том что любая команда на удаление сообщения не работает, вопрос почему.
Вот **ОШИБКА**  (команда hello):

```
Ignoring exception in command hello:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 288, in next
    return self.messages.get_nowait()
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 189, in get_nowait
    raise QueueEmpty
asyncio.queues.QueueEmpty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 377, in purge
    msg = await iterator.next()
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 290, in next
    raise NoMoreItems()
discord.errors.NoMoreItems

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\main.py", line 49, in hello
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 386, in purge
    await ret[-1].delete()
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 1023, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_message(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\llll\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Вот отрывок с кодом:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from lop import token

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='--', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f'Hello {author.mention}!')

bot.run(token)
```

Прошу помочь её решить!

Comment: Ну, если внимательно почитать ошибку `Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` то нетрудно догадаться в чем проблема.

Comment: А как её решить??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У бота нету нужных прав. Выдайте ему роль с правами АДМИНИСТРАТОР